# How are quaternion rotations supposed to behave?

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I've been slowly figuring out quaternions over the past few days and have run into an unexpected issue.  after finally getting the code to work I found that the number I pass to my rotate function is not producing a rotation related to degrees or radians.

This is my rotate function

```
void solveRotation(Quaternion* q, float pitch, bool localx, float yaw, bool localy, float roll, bool localz)
{
    Quaternion temp;
    if(yaw !=0.f)
    { 
        if(localy==true)
        {
            //quaternionMultBA(q, yaw, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
            temp.w = q->w*yaw - q->y;
            temp.x = q->x*yaw + q->z;
            temp.y = q->y*yaw + q->w;
            temp.z = q->z*yaw - q->x;
        }
        else
        {
            //quaternionMultAB(q, yaw, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
            temp.w = q->w*yaw - q->y;
            temp.x = q->x*yaw - q->z;
            temp.y = q->w + q->y*yaw;
            temp.z = q->z*yaw + q->x;
        }
        q->w=temp.w;
        q->x=temp.x;
        q->y=temp.y;
        q->z=temp.z;
    }
    if(pitch != 0.f)
    {
        if(localx==true)
        {

            //quaternionMultBA(q, pitch, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
            temp.w = q->w*pitch - q->x;
            temp.x = q->x*pitch + q->w;
            temp.y = q->y*pitch - q->z;
            temp.z = q->z*pitch + q->y;
        }
        else
        {
            //quaternionMultAB(q, pitch, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
            temp.w = q->w*pitch - q->x;
            temp.x = q->w + q->x*pitch;
            temp.y = q->y*pitch + q->z;
            temp.z = q->z*pitch - q->y;
        }
        q->w=temp.w;
        q->x=temp.x;
        q->y=temp.y;
        q->z=temp.z;
    }
    if(roll != 0.f)
    {
        if(localz==true)
        {

            //quaternionMultBA(q, roll, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
            temp.w = q->w*roll - q->z;
            temp.x = q->x*roll - q->y;
            temp.y = q->y*roll + q->x;
            temp.z = q->z*roll + q->w;
        }
        else
        {
            //quaternionMultAB(q, roll, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
            temp.w = q->w*roll - q->z;
            temp.x = q->x*roll + q->y;
            temp.y = q->y*roll - q->x;
            temp.z = q->z*roll + q->w;
        }
        q->w=temp.w;
        q->x=temp.x;
        q->y=temp.y;
        q->z=temp.z;
    }

    normalize(q);
}
```

the code above gets passed a value depending on which keys have been pressed during that iteration of a loop.  at first I set the value to 0.1 and expected a slow rotation.
instead I saw a large turn per iteration which looked really odd at 60fps.  when I changed the passed value to 1.0 the cube I was working on appeared to do perfect 90 degree turns (the colors moved but the geometry did not)

As I increased the passed amount above 5 I began to see the smooth rotation I was expecting and noticed that it slowed down as I increased the value.  I figured this much out but it really doesn't help me because I can't use it to rotate by specific amounts.  This type of problem is not mentioned in any quaternion tutorials I have read through as they all mention radians.  I'm not sure if I made a mistake or if I'm missing an extra step, or if I screwed up the whole damn thing.

Thanks for help in advance, 
also might be slow to respond

Comment: I don't understand what this code is intended to do.  If pitch, roll, and yaw are supposed to be Euler angles, I'd expect to see some sin and cos calls to make the corresponding quaternions.

Comment: @Jim Lewis, so that is probably what is wrong.  I wrote this under the assumption that to get a quat to rotate by a Euler angle you could multiply it with another quat that has the angle as the w and the axis as the xyz.  So after now looking at the long slow method for converting Euler to quat the right way I would like to know if you could recommend another way.  After all aren't quaternions supposed to be simple?

Answer (score 0):

So I did some more searching and modified my function to include the sin and cos functions I was missing.  I thought I would be able to get away with rotating without trig because of a sample of code I saw on the GPwiki.  Anyways the function is fixed now and if anybody wants to use it-even though there are probably better ones out there-here it is:

```
void solveRotation(Quaternion* q, float pitch, bool localx, float yaw, bool localy, float roll, bool localz)
{
    Quaternion temp;
    float s;
    float c;
    if(yaw !=0.f)
    { 
        yaw*=0.5f;
        s = sin(yaw);
        c = cos(yaw);
        if(localy==true)
        {
            temp.w = q->w*c - q->y*s;
            temp.x = q->x*c + q->z*s;
            temp.y = q->y*c + q->w*s;
            temp.z = q->z*c - q->x*s;
        }
        else
        {
            temp.w = q->w*c - q->y*s;
            temp.x = q->x*c - q->z*s;
            temp.y = q->y*c + q->w*s;
            temp.z = q->z*c + q->x*s;
        }
        q->w=temp.w;
        q->x=temp.x;
        q->y=temp.y;
        q->z=temp.z;
    }
    if(pitch != 0.f)
    {
        pitch*=0.5f;
        s = sin(pitch);
        c = cos(pitch);
        if(localx==true)
        {
            temp.w = q->w*c - q->x*s;
            temp.x = q->x*c + q->w*s;
            temp.y = q->y*c - q->z*s;
            temp.z = q->z*c + q->y*s;
        }
        else
        {
            temp.w = q->w*c - q->x*s;
            temp.x = q->x*c + q->w*s;
            temp.y = q->y*c + q->z*s;
            temp.z = q->z*c - q->y*s;
        }
        q->w=temp.w;
        q->x=temp.x;
        q->y=temp.y;
        q->z=temp.z;
    }
    if(roll != 0.f)
    {
        roll*=0.5f;
        s = sin(roll);
        c = cos(roll);
        if(localz==true)
        {
            temp.w = q->w*c - q->z*s;
            temp.x = q->x*c - q->y*s;
            temp.y = q->y*c + q->x*s;
            temp.z = q->z*c + q->w*s;
        }
        else
        {
            temp.w = q->w*c - q->z*s;
            temp.x = q->x*c + q->y*s;
            temp.y = q->y*c - q->x*s;
            temp.z = q->z*c + q->w*s;
        }
        q->w=temp.w;
        q->x=temp.x;
        q->y=temp.y;
        q->z=temp.z;
    }

    normalize(q);
}
```

btw thanks Jim Lewis